# PHP pass function name as param then call the function?

Tags: php, function, parameters

I need to pass a function as a parameter to another function and then call the passed function from within the function...This is probably easier for me to explain in code..I basically want to do something like this:

```
function ($functionToBeCalled)
{
   call($functionToBeCalled,additional_params);
}
```

Is there a way to do that.. I am using PHP 4.3.9

Thanks!

Answer (score 80, accepted):

I think you are looking for [`call_user_func`](https://www.php.net/function.call-user-func).

An example from the PHP Manual:

```
<?php
function barber($type) {
    echo "You wanted a $type haircut, no problem";
}
call_user_func('barber', "mushroom");
call_user_func('barber', "shave");
?>
```

Comment: and so what happens when barber belongs to a different class? different namespace?

Comment: Is this really the best answer?

It does not demonstrate calling the function from within the function is was passed to as a parameter.

Comment: @abbood - 
public function Foo($function = null)
{
 ...somecode...
 return $this->$function(@params);

}

Comment: This is better solution: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2700433/accept-function-as-parameter-in-php

Answer (score 29):

```
function foo($function) {
  $function(" World");
}
function bar($params) {
  echo "Hello".$params;
}

$variable = 'bar';
foo($variable);
```

Additionally, you can do it this way. See [variable functions](http://us.php.net/manual/en/functions.variable-functions.php).

Comment: I think you're jumping the gun a bit there.  IIRC, that code won't start working until PHP 5.3 comes out.

Comment: “bar” has to be quoted since it’s a string.

Comment: @Jeremy DeGroot variable functions have been around forever

Comment: I forgot the quotes, thanks for pointing that out.  Added them in the edit.  You can do it without quotes in 5.3?

Comment: You can do it without quotes in older versions of PHP.  It turns the unknown symbol into a string, and issues a warning (assuming appropriate reporting) due to the behavior being depreciated (?).

Comment: @tj111, if PHP comes across an unknown CONSTANT it will assume you meant a string.

Comment: Just for reference - in PHP 5.3 passing anonymous (no-name) functions are supported (like you can in JavaScript). They are passed directly. In previous versions of PHP passing functions as a string names is supported.

Answer (score 29):

In php this is very simple.

```
<?php

function here() {
  print 'here';
}


function dynamo($name) {
 $name();
}

//Will work
dynamo('here');
//Will fail
dynamo('not_here');
```

Answer (score 12):

I know the original question asked about PHP 4.3, but now it's a few years later and I just wanted to advocate for my preferred way to do this in PHP 5.3 or higher.

PHP 5.3+ now includes support for [anonymous functions (closures)](http://www.php.net/manual/en/functions.anonymous.php), so you can use some standard functional programming techniques, as in languages like JavaScript and Ruby (with a few caveats). Rewriting the call_user_func example above in "closure style" would look like this, which I find more elegant:

```
$barber = function($type) {
    echo "You wanted a $type haircut, no problem\n";
};

$barber('mushroom');
$barber('shave');
```

Obviously, this doesn't buy you much in this example - the power and flexibility comes when you pass these anonymous functions to other functions (as in the original question). So you can do something like:

```
$barber_cost = function($quantity) {
    return $quantity * 15;
};

$candy_shop_cost = function($quantity) {
    return $quantity * 4.50;   // It's Moonstruck chocolate, ok?
};

function get_cost($cost_fn, $quantity) {
    return $cost_fn($quantity);
}

echo '3 haircuts cost $' . get_cost($barber_cost, 3) . "\n";
echo '6 candies cost $' . get_cost($candy_shop_cost, 6) . "\n";
```

This could be done with call_user_func, of course, but I find this syntax much clearer, especially once namespaces and member variables get involved.

One caveat: I'll be the first to admit I don't know exactly what's going on here, but you can't always call a closure contained in a member or static variable, and possibly in some other cases. But reassigning it to a local variable will allow it to be invoked. So, for example, this will give you an error:

```
$some_value = \SomeNamespace\SomeClass::$closure($arg1, $arg2);
```

But this simple workaround fixes the issue:

```
$the_closure = \SomeNamespace\SomeClass::$closure;
$some_value = $the_closure($arg1, $arg2);
```

Answer (score 11):

You could also use [`call_user_func_array()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.call-user-func-array.php). It allows you to pass an array of parameters as the second parameter so you don't have to know exactly how many variables you're passing.

Answer (score 8):

If you need pass function with parameter as parameter, you can try this:

```
function foo ($param1){
   return $param1;
}

function bar ($foo_function, $foo_param){
    echo $foo_function($foo_param);
}

//call function bar
bar('foo', 'Hi there');  //this will print: 'Hi there'
```

[phpfiddle example](http://phpfiddle.org/lite?code=%3C?php%5Cnfunction%20foo%20($param1)%7B%5Cn%20return%20$param1;%5Cn%7D%5Cn%5Cnfunction%20bar%20($foo_function,%20$foo_param)%7B%5Cn%20echo%20$foo_function($foo_param);%5Cn%7D%5Cn%5Cn//call%20function%20bar%5Cnbar(%27foo%27,%20%27Hi%20there%27);%5Cn%5Cn?%3E%5Cn)

Hope it'll be helpful...

Comment: Can anyone confirm?

Comment: http://phpfiddle.org/lite?code=%3C?php%5Cnfunction%20foo%20($param1)%7B%5Cn%20return%20$param1;%5Cn%7D%5Cn%5Cnfunction%20bar%20($foo_function,%20$foo_param)%7B%5Cn%20echo%20$foo_function($foo_param);%5Cn%7D%5Cn%5Cn//call%20function%20bar%5Cnbar(%27foo%27,%20%27Hi%20there%27);%5Cn%5Cn?%3E%5Cn

Answer (score -1):

If you want to do this inside a PHP Class, take a look at this code:

```
// Create a sample class
class Sample
{

    // Our class displays 2 lists, one for images and one for paragraphs
    function __construct( $args ) {
        $images = $args['images'];
        $items  = $args['items'];
        ?>
        <div>
            <?php 
            // Display a list of images
            $this->loop( $images, 'image' ); 
            // notice how we pass the name of the function as a string

            // Display a list of paragraphs
            $this->loop( $items, 'content' ); 
            // notice how we pass the name of the function as a string
            ?>
        </div>
        <?php
    }

    // Reuse the loop
    function loop( $items, $type ) {
        // if there are items
        if ( $items ) {
            // iterate through each one
            foreach ( $items as $item ) {
                // pass the current item to the function
                $this->$type( $item ); 
                // becomes $this->image 
                // becomes $this->content
            }
        }
    }

    // Display a single image
    function image( $item ) {
        ?>
        <img src="<?php echo $item['url']; ?>">
        <?php 
    }

    // Display a single paragraph
    function content( $item ) {
        ?>
        <p><?php echo $item; ?></p>
        <?php 
    }
}

// Create 2 sample arrays
$images = array( 'image-1.jpg', 'image-2.jpg', 'image-3.jpg' );
$items  = array( 'sample one', 'sample two', 'sample three' );

// Create a sample object to pass my arrays to Sample
$elements = { 'images' => $images, 'items' => $items }

// Create an Instance of Sample and pass the $elements as arguments
new Sample( $elements );
```

Comment: "Look at this code" followed by a wall of text is not terribly helpful. Especially when answering a 10 year old question with 6 other answers. Explain what this code does, and how it provides a better approach than others already mentioned here.

Comment: Hi @miken32! Thanks for your observation. Where you able to take a look at the comments inside the block?

The reason why I believe this is helpful is because it provides an specific context where a novice developer can see the function argument working inside a Class.

Do you have any recommendations?

Comment: miken is right.  The block is too extensive, especially for a novice.  People just want a quick solution first, and then if it might work for them, they may want a more detailed one.