# Create PHP function that takes function as a parameter

Tags: php, function

I am trying to create a PHP function that takes another PHP function as input. Here is an example:

```
function getMean(function){
    $allUsers =  getAllUsers();
    $sum = 0;

    foreach ($allUsers  as $currentUser ){

        $sum =+ (function($currentUser['CONSUMER_ID'], 5, 8))/(8-5);

    }

}
```

Comment: can u explain your question a little better?

Comment: probably a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2700433/pass-function-as-parameter-in-php

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Perhaps something like this should do it. PHP has a "type" called callback, which can be a closure (as of PHP 5.3), name of a function or array containing object and the method to call. These callbacks can be called with `call_user_func()`

```
function getMean($callback){
    $allUsers =  getAllUsers();
    $sum = 0;

    foreach ($allUsers  as $currentUser ){
        $sum =+ (call_user_func($callback, $currentUser['CONSUMER_ID'], 5, 8))/(8-5);
    }

    return $sum;
}
```

Comment: since you cant type hint you might want to warp it in a  if block with `is_callable($callback)`.

Answer (score 2):

You need PHP 5.3 to do that natively.

```
function getMean($function){
    $allUsers =  getAllUsers();
    $sum = 0;

    foreach ($allUsers  as $currentUser ){

        $sum += ($function($currentUser['CONSUMER_ID'], 5, 8))/(8-5);
    }
    return $sum;
}

getMean(function($consumer_id, $five, $eight) {
    return $consumer_id;
});
```

I you run PHP 5.3- (lower than 5.3), you need to use a callback ([documentation is here](http://php.net/callback)) along with the [`call_user_func()`](http://php.net/call_user_func) or [`call_user_func_array()`](http://php.net/call_user_func_array) function.

Answer (score 0):

you can do that as long as `function($currentUser['CONSUMER_ID'], 5, 8)` returns something

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the PHP [Eval](http://php.net/manual/en/function.eval.php) function is what you are looking for. Pass the getMean function a string, and then change the line to have $sum =+ (eval($param) .....)

Security is a problem though because any function can be passed.

Comment: No. The callback type is undoubtedly better here.

Comment: Learn something new every day

Answer (score 0):

Save the function as a variable.

```
$function = function($param1){ //code here }
```

and pass it to your other function as a parameter.

```
function getMean($function)
{
  //code here
  $sum += $function($param);
}
```

[edit]

[PHP.net Manual - Variable Functions](http://php.net/manual/en/functions.variable-functions.php)

Comment: I believe this requires php >= 5.3.0

Comment: @whoughton It does not specify in the documentation, but I think you are right.

Comment: I think yours is actually an anonymous function/closure, as opposed to a variable function. http://php.net/manual/en/functions.anonymous.php

Answer (score 0):

are you searching for [anonymous functions](https://www.php.net/manual/en/functions.anonymous.php)?

Felix

Answer (score 0):

If you want to dynamically create  a function in php < 5.3 then youre stuck with using [`create_function`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.create-function.php). Becuase of how you use this function its really insane to use it for anything but but creating simple function for `array_map`,`array_walk` or things that do simple calculations or basic text processing.

If youre doing anything more complex than that its much easier and less of a headache to simply define the function as normal and then use it with `call_user_func` or `call_user_func_array` as others have suggested.

DO NOT USE `eval` :-)