# How to pass an external $var into a function()

Tags: php, function, oop

Now, have a look into my `page.php`, I'll explain my problem inside it.

```
<?php
$var= "<p>Hello world</p>";

function myfunction1($a){
echo $a;
}

//then
myfunction1($var);//-->OK, return "Hello world!"


//but, the thing is, i don't want to pass any argument into myfunction(), 
//so i have to import the external $var into myfuntion2()


function myfunction2(nothing here){
//what's here?
}

myfunction2();//i want to do this

?>
```

Of course, if i wrap all this inside a CLASS, then `myfunction()` and `$var`  turn into `method $amp; property`  (OOP style), 
these will be so easy to access! But i don't want to do that!

so, is it possible? Can anyone give me an suggestion? Thanks

Comment: Add `global $var;` inside `myfunction2()`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you do not want to pass any params in your function than only way to do is use the `global`

```
function myfunction2(){
     global $var;
}
```

But I should warn you that using `global` is extremely bad, so do not use it unless you know how it behaves. Your `global $var` can be altered in your function so for example

```
$var = 2; //Initial value
function myfunction2(){
     global $var;
     $var = 'changed';
}
myfunction2(); //$var is now holding 'changed'. 2 is now lost
```

So from now on your `$var` will hold the string `changed` as the `$var` has a `global` scope, it's no more local to the function.

Alternatively you can read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2700433/pass-function-as-parameter-in-php) answer to pass a function as function parameter

Answer (score 1):

You can do this in modern versions of PHP:

```
$var = 'World';
$func = function() use($var){
  echo "Hello $var";
};

$func(); //=> Hello World
```

Answer (score 0):

Or use a Singleton:

```
function myfunction2(){
    echo MySingleton::getInstance()->var2;
}
```

Comment: I doubt the OP knows what I singleton is. CS books I've used teach global variables before classes.

Comment: Thanks, i'll think about using Singleton, and test this later!, anyway, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You have to declare variable as global in function then you can use variable inside function without passing it as parametr.

like this,

```
<?php
   $var= "<p>Hello world</p>";

   function myfunction1($a){
     echo $a;
   }
  //then
  myfunction1($var);//-->OK, return "Hello world!"

  //but, the thing is, i don't want to pass any argument into myfunction(), so i  have to    import the external $var into myfuntion2()
  function myfunction2(){
     global $var;
     echo $var;
  }

  myfunction2();//i want to do this

?>
```