# PHP: "Broadcast message" between two functions

Tags: php

I am currently trying to create "extensions" for a project I made.
I want to create "broadcasts" so that extensions can get triggered when something happens. Here is an example of what I want to do:

```
class mainproject {
 public static function dosomething() {
  runsomething();
  self::save();
 }
 public static function save() {
  savesomething();
  broadcast("saved it");
 }
}

class extension extends mainproject {
 onBroadcast("saved it", function() {
  dosomething();
 });
}
```

Is is possible? Or are there other ways of achieving this?

Wordpress has something similar with`add_action( 'admin_menu', 'function_name' );`

Comment: You should look into how Laravel does events: https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/events

Comment: Why not pass a function on the event trigger? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2700433/accept-function-as-parameter-in-php

Answer (score 0):

I have found a solution that works for me: https://gist.github.com/im4aLL/548c11c56dbc7267a2fe96bda6ed348b