# How to call a function with other function as argument

Tags: php

im just learning php
Im trying to add a log with comments to my functions output.
Right now it looks like this:

```
//the function
function add1($x){
  if($GLOBALS['logging'] === 'on'){ $log[] = 'Adding 1 to '.$x;};
  $a = $x + 1;
  if($GLOBALS['logging'] === 'on'){
    $return[] = $a;
    $return[] = $log;
    return $return;
  }else{ return $a; };
};
//calling the function
  if($GLOBALS['logging'] === 'on'){
    $return = add1($x);
    $number = $return[0];
    $log = $return[1];
  }else{ $number = add1($x); };
```

Im kinda annoyed by the fact i need to retype this if statement.
So i made a seperate function for returning the function
which looks like this:

```
    //function
    function log_return($data = 'x', $log = 'x'){
    if($GLOBALS['logging'] === 'on'){
      if($data !== 'x') $return[] = $data;
      if($log !== 'x') $return[] = $log;
      return $return;
    } return $data;

};//function end
```

And returning it with:

```
 return $return = isset($log) ? log_return($data, $log) : log_return($data);
```

Now my quastion is: Is there a way to call a function with function..
like:

```
call_function(add1($x));
```

so i can return it either with log or without..

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2700433/accept-function-as-parameter-in-php

Comment: Don't use $GLOBALS.  Pass parameters you need into your functions.  It's safer, self documenting, and can catch errors especially if you use type hinting that is now available in PHP.

Comment: This is very much the reason that many frameworks are built around the dependency injection pattern.  I highly recommend:  http://fabien.potencier.org/what-is-dependency-injection.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given the answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/2700760/5387193 - this should work:

```
function add1($a)
{
    // add1 code goes here
}

function call_function($name, $param)
{
    $name($param);
}
call_function('add1', $x);
```

On a side note, your variable and function names aren't very intuitive. Perhaps you should study how to write good quality readable code. I recommend reading chapter 9 of Refactoring by Martin Fowler, it's quite good. You can find a PDF version on the web.

Another note, your return statement `return $return = isset($log) ? log_return($data, $log) : log_return($data);` has a unnecessary assignment to $return. The code should simply read

```
return isset($log) ? log_return($data, $log) : log_return($data);
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is possible. To simplify:

```
function first($x) {
    return $x+1;
}
function second($y) {
    return $y+1;
}
echo second(first(1)); // Returns 3, ie. 1+1+1
```

Answer (score 1):

As gview said in his comment, don't use global variables.  Argument lists exist for several reasons, included but not limited to making code easier to read, edit, and debug.  The same goes for function and variable names.

Moreover, your code is very messy. It can be consolidated:

```
function addTo($currentValue, $valueToAdd, $logging = 0)
{
    if ($logging) {
        logWrite('addTo', "Adding $valueToAdd to $currentValue");
        return $currentValue + $valueToAdd;
    } else {
        return $currentValue;
    }
}

function logWrite($operation, $message)
{
    $log = getLog(); // maybe it's a file, or DB record or something
    // perform the write, depending on your implementation
}

$number = addTo($someStaringValue, $someOtherValue, 1);
```

All of this said, logging should not control program flow.  In other words, whether something is logged by the system or not should have no bearing on what your code is trying to do.  I really think you need to take a broader view of what you're trying to do and break it up into components.

At best, your code should tell a logger to log info, and the logger itself should determine if logging is actually turned on.  If it is, the info is logged.  If not, then the code that calls on the logger still works and goes about its business.

Comment: thanks for the reply, i'll rewrite the code without globals, and yes the log is turned on(file or screen)/off. Got a lot to work on.. trying to consolidate as much as possible.