# PHP Pass a function as a parameter in another function

Tags: php, oop

I have two functions - the first function is complex and it takes around 15 seconds to load as it fetches data from third parties. The second one is a normal function. To illustrate this is what I have

```
<?php
class ComplexFunctions{

public function complexFunctionOne($x){
// do something
}

}

?>

<?php

function SimpleFunction($y, $z){
if($y){
// if $y is true use variable z
}else{
//if $y is false don't use variable z
}
return $a;
}

$cf = new ComplexFunctions();

$input_y = 'Y';
$input_y = 'Z';
$output = SimpleFunction($input_y, $cf->complexFunctionOne($input_y);

?>
```

I need to run the complex function `$y` only when the first variable `$y` is true. If it isn't I don't want to run it.

Unfortunately, regardless of whether `$y` is true or false - `$cf->complexFunctionOne($input_y)` is still loaded in any condition. This could take a lot of useless time for something that I do not want unless it's called specifically.

One solution could be to call `$cf->complexFunctionOne($input_y)` inside teh simple function, however, I have a hand full of complex functions e.g. complexFunctionTwo and I only want to use depending on the circumstance rather than have a Switch/Case statement.

Comment: Consider checking [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2700433/accept-function-as-parameter-in-php).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

well in order to pass a function, you can just:

```
$output = SimpleFunction($input_y, function() use ($input_y, $cf){ 
    return $cf->complexFunctionOne($input_y);
};
```

so then you just need:

```
function SimpleFunction($y, $z){
  if($y){
     // if $y is true use variable z
     $a = $z();
  }else{
     //if $y is false don't use variable z
     $a = ...;
  }
  return $a;
}
```

In this way you will "lazy load" the result of `$z`

Comment: Arrow function would be more concise way to create an anonymous function. `$output = SimpleFunction($input_y, fn() => $cf->complexFunctionOne($input_y));`

Comment: @miken32 he has not mentioned the PHP version... so I used this to avoid syntax problems