# How to set variable in a function variable in php?

Tags: php, function

I have a function variable like this...
        $aName = "My Name";

```
$sayHelloFunction = public function sayHello($aName){
       echo($aName);
    }
```

and I have something like this.....

```
callAFunctionFromFunction($sayHelloFunction);
```

Inside the "callAFunctionFromFunction", I do this:

```
            if(is_callable($sayHelloFunction)) { 
                  $sayHelloFunction(); 
        }
```

I found that the "My Name" can't display, what did I do wrong...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest you to look [here](http://us.php.net/manual/en/functions.variable-functions.php) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/627775/php-pass-function-as-param-then-call-the-function) as these exact threads deal with passing a function as a parameter. Also closures (anonymous functions) in PHP have no name (that's why they are called anonymous), so what you should do is something like that.

```
<?php $sayHelloFunction = function($aName){
   echo($aName);
};
if(is_callable($sayHelloFunction)) $sayHelloFunction("Testing 1,2,3");
```

Comment: Well, [closures have been added in PHP 5.3](http://php.net/manual/en/functions.anonymous.php). Only `public` is invalid here.

Answer (score 2):

The function sayHello expects a parameter $aName, but when you call it you don't pass in a value.

You would need to do this:

```
    if(is_callable($sayHelloFunction)) { 
              $sayHelloFunction("Hello John"); 
    }
```

Also you can't use the public access type with closures.

```
 $sayHelloFunction = function sayHello($aName) {
    echo($aName);
 }
```