# Run function using another function

Tags: php

How can I make this work, I dont know why it's not working

```
public function generateCourse($course, $type) {
    $this->runFunction($this->generateHole($hole), $type);
}

public function runFunction($function, $type) {
        switch ($type){
            case 0:
                for ($hole = 0; $hole < 18; $hole++) {
                    $function;
                }
                break;
```

Comment: 1. *this work* What should it do? 2. *it's not working* What does that mean? Do you get any errors? wrong results?

Comment: possible duplicate of [PHP pass function as param then call the function?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/627775/php-pass-function-as-param-then-call-the-function)

Comment: Please add what the expected result should be, and what error messages you are encountering.  It'll make it easier to understand your problem.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
public function runFunction($function, $type) {
        switch ($type){
            case 0:
                for ($hole = 0; $hole < 18; $hole++) {
                    $function();
                }
```

or call the function with this

```
call_user_func($function);
```