# PHP function as parameter of another function

Tags: php

In PHP can we do this?

```
function foo($c) {
  $c;

  echo 'done';
}

foo(function() {
  echo 'test'
});
```

Such that the output will be:

```
testdone
```

---

This was my real problem :

```
function create_transaction($obj, $func, $errorMsg)
{
  try {
    $obj->transaction('START');

    $func();

    $obj->transaction('COMMIT');
  } catch(Exception $e) {
    $obj->transaction('ROLLBACK');
    throw new exception($errorMsg . ' ---> ' . $e);
  }
}
```

So i can call this function of create_transaction like this :

```
create_transaction($obj, function() {
  echo 'test';

  // this should be a database CRUD process
  // to make it simple, i just put echo.
}, 'error');
```

create_transaction() will inserted the function code between the START and COMMIT.

But this way return an error :

```
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_FUNCTION
```

This error is in line where i wrote :

```
create_transaction($obj, function() { // Error here
```

Comment: can you please check this link i think it may helps you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/627775/php-pass-function-as-param-then-call-the-function

Comment: It should work if you execute function c `$c()` (in the body of `foo`).

Comment: @arjan, the problem is, function c() is dynamic, i want to inject some other code to foo(), so whatever the the process in $c, when it is done, it will echo "done".

Comment: @dinesh I'm sorry, i didn't get what you're trying to say. in the page you give me, it written this : "call_user_func('barber', "mushroom");" its the same like this : "barber('mushroom')" right?, why use call_user_func() if you can call the function directly. and what it has to do with my question ?, im sorry, i fail to grasp your point.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you are doing is calling an ['anonymous function'](http://php.net/manual/en/functions.anonymous.php). You are passing the anonymous (which is anonymous because it's unnamed) to another function that invokes it. However, you're not actually invoking it! Specifically because you have encoded `$c;` rather than `$c()`.

This works as expected:

```
<?php

function execute_closure($f) {
  echo "Before executing enclosure.\n";

  $f(); //The parens cause php to execute the function

  echo "After executing enclosure.\n";
}

execute_closure(function() {
  echo "Executing enclosured function.\n";
});
```

Placing this in a file called `callfunction.php` and executing it yields:

```
$ php callfunction.php  
Before executing enclosure. 
Executing enclosured function. 
After executing enclosure.
```

As a final note: anonymous functions only work in PHP 5.3+.

Comment: I'm sorry, i didn't get what you're trying to say. in the page you give me, it written this : "call_user_func('increment', $a);" its the same like this : "increment($a)" right?, why use call_user_func() if you can call the function directly.

Comment: @MarcelAng I think misunderstood your original question. I've updated my response, but this means this is largely a syntax error on your part.

Comment: AHA !, this what i meant, what i've done is similar to your way. but in the line "execute_closure(function() {" it return an error : "Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_FUNCTION". I'll update my question with actual problem.

Comment: Ah nevermind !, i found the problem !. Its my php version, i read in your documentation its php 5.3 above, i used 5.2.

Answer (score 0):

```
        <?php

            function foo($c) {
                // CALL THE CALLABLE HERE INSTEAD
                try{
                    $strVal = $c();
                    if(is_string($strVal)){
                        echo $strVal . 'done';
                    }else{
                        // YOUR FUNCTION IS NOT RETURNING A STRING: CATCH & HANDLE THAT CASE:
                        echo "The passed-in Argument Must return a String value...";
                        return false;
                    }
                }catch(Exception $e){
                    // HANDLE THE EXCEPTION YOUR WAY.
                    echo "The passed-in Argument Must be a Callable Function and should return a String value...";
                }
            }

            foo(function() {
                //RETURN THE VALUE HERE!!!
                return "test";
            });

            // SHOULD ECHO BACK 'testdone' TO THE OUTPUT STREAM...
```

Comment: Are you sure that code works ?, because it return an error : "Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_FUNCTION".

Comment: @MarcelAng Someone down here should be asking you the same Question. if you want to test it yourself, here you go: https://eval.in/571505