# Is there a more elegant way to pass a function to another function in PhP?

Tags: php, function

It can be done by passing the function name in a string [PHP pass function as param then call the function?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/627775/php-pass-function-as-param-then-call-the-function)

Well that is very crude.

No type checking

If I refactor the function name the string containing the variable need to be fixed too manually. If we have a typo it won't be checked on compile time.

It's not like in vb.net where we have addressOf operator.

Is this really the only way to do this in PhP?

I mean the lamda function seems more sane. At least the variable we pass is really a functio6 and not a string.

Am I wrong here?

Is the right way to do this is to use lambda?

Or is there any other way?

I can use closures like this

```
function getSelectedElements($textFile)
{

    $standardfuncline2= function (&$arout,$line)
    {
        standardfuncline1 ($arout,$line);
    };
    $result = getSelectedElementsCustomFunc ($textFile,$standardfuncline2);
    return $result;
}
```

instead of

```
$result = getSelectedElementsCustomFunc ($textFile,"standardfuncline1");
```

That seems to be more proven with all type checking and stuffs. However, kind of too long isn't it?

Comment: What problem are you trying to solve? What's the real question?

Comment: One deleted answer address that. I don't like passing function as "string" I want some compile time checking.

Comment: PHP doesn't compile. It gets parsed and then interpreted. There is absolutely no "compile time" checking for functions.

Comment: show some code demonstrating the issue you're referring to and attempting to resolve.

Comment: The question that you referenced is based on a very old version of PHP, before anonymous functions became available in 5.3. In that old version, passing the function name by string was the way to do it. That way still works, but now you also have closures. Both ways are useful, depending on the context.

Comment: There's an elegant way. Wrap the function in a class and pass the instance of said class as a parameter instead. Please, for whatever reason, do not try to call functions using strings. That code would not even pass code review under my lead, because it's simply unreadable.

Comment: trincot answer is fine. I will put addition to that and hope for some comment from David Packer.

Comment: barmar is even better but he deletes his answer.

Comment: NB: I see Barmar's answer, but it has an error: the code he posted gave a parsing error. I suppose that is why he deleted it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can define your function as a closure, i.e. an anonymous function which can be assigned to a variable or passed as a function argument directly. The following example is taken from the [PHP docs on callables](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.callable.php#example-114):

> #### Callback example using a Closure
>
> ```
> <?php  
> // Our closure
> $double = function($a) {
>     return $a * 2;
> };
>
> // This is our range of numbers
> $numbers = range(1, 5);
>
> // Use the closure as a callback here to
> // double the size of each element in our
> // range
> $new_numbers = array_map($double, $numbers);
>
> print implode(' ', $new_numbers);
> ?>
> ```
>
> The above example will output:
>
> ```
> 2 4 6 8 10
> ```

More variants on the above can be found in the [PHP documentation on anonymous functions](http://php.net/manual/en/functions.anonymous.php).

#### When referencing an existing function

There is no such solution for functions that are defined in the usual way, but you can encapsulate them as a Callable:

```
// Your already existing function:
function myFunc($arg) {
    echo "running myFunc with '$arg'.";
}

// The new Callable wrapper for it:
$myFunc = function ($arg) {
    myFunc($arg);
};

// Calling it (same as in first solution)
call_user_func($myFunc, 'test');
```

Comment: What about if you want to call an existing function?

Comment: Then you use this principle to make a callable wrapper for it. See the section I added to my answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can sure do some `Type-Hinting` even when using `call_user_func()` like so:

```
    /**
     * @var $arrActions array  
     * @return mixed
     */
    function doSomething(array $arrActions) {  // TYPE HINT ARRAY
        $output = "";
        if(is_array($arrActions)) {
            foreach ($arrActions as $action) {
                $output .= "Have you already performed Action Nr. $action ?\n";
            }
        }
        return $output;
    }
    // CALL WITH ARRAY AS ARGUMENT..
    var_dump( call_user_func('doSomething', ["one", "two", "three"]) );

    // PRODUCES:
    string 'Have you already performed Action Nr. one ?
            Have you already performed Action Nr. two ?
            Have you already performed Action Nr. three ?
            ' (length=134)


    // CALL WITH STRING AS ARGUMENT..
    var_dump( call_user_func('doSomething', "one"]) );

   // PRODUCES:
    Fatal error: Uncaught TypeError: Argument 1 passed to doSomething() must be of the type array, string given....
```